# Rotated multi-column header in booktabs

Tags: tables, rotating, booktabs, vertical, header

I want to gernerate a cross table with booktabs. Therfore, I have 2 data sets I want to compare to each other.

The table should look like the pic below but I do not get it to write the vertical header properly. Maybe somebody can help?

[image]

I want to get a rotated header from row 8 to row 2 with a line break before "Data2". And if possible, another vertical cmidrule would be nice.

Here is a MWE :) Thanks a lot!

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, headsepline]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{cccccccc}
    \toprule
    & & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\thead{Long text for Data1}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){3-8}
    & & \thead{0} & \thead{1} & \thead{2} & \thead{3} & \thead{5} & \thead{10}\\
    \midrule
    \multirowcell{6}[0pt]{\rothead{Long text for\\Data2}}& \thead{0} & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% \\
    & \thead{1} & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% \\
    & \thead{2} & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% \\
    & \thead{3} & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% \\
    & \thead{5} & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% \\
    & \thead{10} & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `\raisebox` and a `\rotatebox` in the last row, first cell. The heading is type set in a `\parbox` inside the `\rotatebox`:

**Example 1 – raisebox, rotatebox and parbox**

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, headsepline]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{p{1cm}>{\bfseries}ccccccc}
    \toprule
    & & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\thead{Long text for Data1}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){3-8}
    & & \thead{0} & \thead{1} & \thead{2} & \thead{3} & \thead{5} & \thead{10}\\
    \midrule
    & 0 & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% \\
    & 1 & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% \\
    & 2 & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% \\
    & 3 & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% \\
    & 5 & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% \\
\raisebox{35pt}[0pt][0pt]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox{2.5cm}{\centering Long text for \\ Data2}}}    & 10 & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Example 2 – raisebox, rotatebox and nested tabular**

Another possible solution is using nested tabular inside the `\rotatebox`. The `tabular` is type set by defining a new command, `\tstack`. The vertical rule is a `\cmidrule` that is fined tuned to extend until it meet the horizontal rules. The per cent sign (%) I have moved from cell/column to heading. You may consider to reduce the font size in the headings to `footnotesize` to make them less dominant.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, headsepline]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs, array}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

% Multi-line left-aligned text with manual line breaks.
% The base line of the whole is at the top row.
\newcommand*{\tstack}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1}%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}>{\bfseries}c@{}}#1\\\cmidrule(l{-0.65em}r{-0.65em}){1-1} \end{tabular}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}>{\bfseries}rcccccc}
    \toprule
    & & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\thead{Long text for Data1}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){3-8}
    & & \thead{0 (\%)}  & \thead{1 (\%)} & \thead{2 (\%)} & \thead{3 (\%)} & \thead{5 (\%)} & \thead{10 (\%)}\\
    \midrule
    & 0 & ??? & ??? & ??? & ??? & ??? & ??? \\
    & 1 & ??? & ??? & ??? & ??? & ??? & ??? \\
    & 2 & ??? & ??? & ??? & ??? & ??? & ??? \\
    & 3 & ??? & ??? & ??? & ??? & ??? & ??? \\
    & 5 & ??? & ??? & ??? & ??? & ??? & ??? \\
\raisebox{47pt}[0pt][0pt]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\tstack{Long text for \\ Data2}}}    & 10 & ??? & ??? & ??? & ??? & ??? & ??? \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Example 3 – nested tabular and vertical rule**

[image]

If you accept small gaps between the vertical rule in column 1 and the horizontal rules (which I think s OK in this tabular), a more automatic solution is to use an ordinary rule (`|`) between column 1 and column 2, which you cancel with a multicolumn in row 1 and row. In the example below I have also reduced the font size, which is more pleasant when you use bold.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, headsepline]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs, array}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\footnotesize}

% Multi-line left-aligned text with manual line breaks.
% The base line of the whole is at the top row.
\newcommand*{\tstack}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1}%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\footnotesize\bfseries\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.1cm}|>{\bfseries}rcccccc@{}}
    \toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}       & & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\thead{Long text for Data1}} \\
    \cmidrule(l){3-8}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}       & & \thead{0\,(\%)}  & \thead{1\,(\%)} & \thead{2\,(\%)} & \thead{3\,(\%)} & \thead{5\,(\%)} & \thead{10\,(\%)}\\
    \midrule
    & 0 & ??? & ??? & ??? & ??? & ??? & ??? \\
    & 1 & ??? & ??? & ??? & ??? & ??? & ??? \\
    & 2 & ??? & ??? & ??? & ??? & ??? & ??? \\
    & 3 & ??? & ??? & ??? & ??? & ??? & ??? \\
    & 5 & ??? & ??? & ??? & ??? & ??? & ??? \\
\raisebox{44pt}[0pt][0pt]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\tstack{Long text for \\ Data2}}}    & 10 & ??? & ??? & ??? & ??? & ??? & ??? \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution with only `\thead`, cheating with the number of rows in `\multirow`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, headsepline]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
\settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont Long text for}
   \begin{tabular}{cccccccc}
    \toprule
    & & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\thead{Long text for Data1}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){3-8}
    & & \thead{0} & \thead{1} & \thead{2} & \thead{3} & \thead{5} & \thead{10}\\
    \midrule
  \multirow{8}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\thead{Long text for\\ Data2}}} & \thead{0} & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% \\
    & \thead{1} & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% \\
    & \thead{2} & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% \\
    & \thead{3} & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% \\
    & \thead{5} & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% \\
    & \thead{10} & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since you define size of `\rothead` I expect that instead of `\multirow{8}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\thead{Long text for\\ Data2}}}` you will write `\multirow{8}{*}{\rothead{\centering Long text for\\ Data2}}` :-)

Comment: @Zarko: That's one of the things I tried first, but the (horizontal) placement f the vertical text wasn't what I expected. Yet I needed o define size of the text to make the code work correctly.

Comment: Using @Allan Munn patch `\makeatletter   
\def\@rothead[#1]#2{\thead{\\[-.65\normalbaselineskip]
  \turn{\cellrotangle}\thead[#1]{#2}\endturn}}
\makeatother`  (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8149/) in preamble and than `\multirow{8}{*}{\rothead[c]{Long text for\\ Data2}}` gives the same result as your approach. Of course, your solution works very wel :-)

Comment: @Zarko: I didn't know this patch, thanks for the information! It's been quite some time that I've noticed problems with ` \rothead/cell` except in very simple cases, but the package doesn't seem to be maintained, just like `floatrow` from the same author.

Comment: You are right about maintaining, and this is pity. Beside mention patch also exist patch for use of `m` column type (from @Ulrike Fischer, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319768/). I would be very glad, if some make fix of the `makecell` package with this two patch (for example similarly as was partly done for the `tabu` package). Unfortunately I'm not skilled for such job :-(

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. This environment is similar with `{tabular}` (of `array`) but provides some other functionnalies.

In `{NiceTabular}`, you merge cells both horizontally and vertically with the command `\Block`. For the rows, you give the number of *logical* rows (and not the number of physical lines as with `\multicolumn`).

A built-in command `\rotate` is provided to rotate the content of the block.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, headsepline]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
   \begin{NiceTabular}{>{\bfseries}c>{\bfseries}ccccccc}[cell-space-limits=3pt]
    \toprule
    \RowStyle[nb-rows=2]{\bfseries}
    & & \Block{1-6}{Long text for Data1} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){3-8}
    & & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 10 \\
    \midrule
  \Block{6-1}<\rotate>{Long text for\\ Data2}
    & 0  & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% \\
    & 1  & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% \\
    & 2  & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% \\
    & 3  & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% \\
    & 5  & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% \\
    & 10 & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% & ???\,\% \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]